# What is the efficient way of generating unique random number?

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

I am looking to generate a random number for every user contribution as a title of the contribution.

I could simply check the database each time with a query and generate a number which does not equal to any of the entries of the database. But I imagine this as inefficient and it could become slow if the database is big in my opinion. Also I'd have to contain all the numbers of the database somewhere to manage the "not equals to", in an array or something similar but that can end up as a giant one.

Excuse the layman's speech I am new to this.

Any suggestions how this can be solved efficiently without straining the resources too much? You can explain it linguistically and do not have to provide me any scripts, I will figure it out.

Comment: for a unique id - php has uniqid() and most db's have something to UUID for mysql

Comment: any reason why you can't use `auto_increment` from the database?

Comment: Book of Zeus, the random unique ID is meant to be the title of the user contribution, an auto increment would make the page look industrial and take out its life, random numbers make it look more lively.

Comment: With random numbers, there is no guarantee of uniqueness. The same number can randomly be generated more than once.

Comment: Dragon and Jonathan, uniqid seems like a solution, though I am wondering what Jonathan approached, how does that function ensure the ID is really unique and does not recreate the same ID twice coincidentally?

Comment: @Carpet i get your point. thanks for the explaination

Comment: the manual page explains how it works, it basically uses the date and time, as the current date and time will never be repeated (until the universe collapses and time runs backwards), it's a safe starting point.

Comment: Based on what you describe, the best thing I can think of is a UUID/GUID that incorporates time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). I'm not sure how portable it is.

Example:

```
printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());
```

Will output something like:

```
uniqid(): 4b3403665fea6
```

Comment: uniqid() works great, I just tried it, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

uniqid() will give you a random number that can technically repeat.

Maybe you can apply a simple algorithm on an auto-increment field? n(n+1)/2 or something?